# What is the service name for the EntityManager in Breeze?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, breeze

I just don't understand what I have to set as the service name for the EntityManager.

I hava two controllers: an ApiController and a 'normal' controller:

API Controller:

```
[BreezeController]
public class TournamentApiController : ApiController
{
    private EFContextProvider<TournamentContext> _contextProvider;

    public TournamentApiController()
    {
        _contextProvider = new EFContextProvider<TournamentContext>();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public string Metadata()
    {
        return _contextProvider.Metadata();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<Tournament> Tournaments()
    {
        return _contextProvider.Context.Tournaments;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<Team> Teams()
    {
        return _contextProvider.Context.Teams;
    }
}
```

'Normal' controller:

```
public class TournamentController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }

    public ActionResult Details()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }
}
```

And in my DataSrvice.js file:

```
app.dataservice = (function (breeze) {

breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstance("modelLibrary", "backingStore", true);

var serviceName = '/TournamentApi'; // What exactly do I need to set here? 

// *** Cross origin service example  ***
//var serviceName = 'http://todo.breezejs.com/breeze/todos'; // controller in different origin

var manager = new breeze.EntityManager(serviceName);
// manager.enableSaveQueuing(true);

var dataservice = {
    getAllTournaments: getAllTournaments,
};
return dataservice;

/*** implementation details ***/
function getAllTournaments() {
    var query = breeze.EntityQuery
            .from("Tournament");

    return manager.executeQuery(query);
}
})(breeze);
```

Can someone explain what is meant by a service name and thus, what I should use as the service name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The serviceName identifies the service end-point, the route to the Web API controller.  This will be the "root" of the URL you use to communicate with the server.  So if the actual endpoints to query 'teams'  and 'tournaments' are

```
 http://foo/bar/tournamentApp/teams ...
 http://foo/bar/tournamentApp/tournaments ...
```

then your service name will be

```
"foo/bar/tournamentApp"
```

Comment: Thank you. So it's just the path to the APIController with the Breeze attribute.